# Progress bar in custom dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-progressbar

I wanted to add a progressbar within a custom dialog in listview.My dialog is

```
dialog = new Dialog(RegestrationActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_qulification);
    dialog.setTitle("State");
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ListViewQualification = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ListViewQualification);

    ProgressBarStateQuali = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarStateQuali);


        ProgressBarStateQuali.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ListViewQualification.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ProgressBarStateQuali.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ListViewQualification.setAdapter(adapterState);
        ListViewQualification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dialog.show();
```

But it is not working

Comment: If your are making custom dialog, I would suggest making DialogFragment

Comment: Ok, is it possible in any way to add progress bar in this type of custom dialog??

Comment: yes, you can add whatever you want, it will have a complete different view, add spinners or whatever

Answer (score 2):

You have set visibility Gone to your progress bar, remove it it will work:

```
     ProgressBarStateQuali.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: then what's this? `ProgressBarStateQuali.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ?

Comment: it's  set on first line ProgressBarStateQuali.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), on next line it's change to GONE.

Comment: oh yes, my bad, I thought that one is another progress bar,